# How to programmatically update ember input field

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I am developing an Ember Application that takes user input in input field and formats it in American currency and then shows the formatted value to user.

The **template** is:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    {{input value=savings id="userSavings"}}
    <p>Formatted Savings={{formattedSavings}}</p>
</script>
```

The **Controller** is:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
savings:null,

formattedSavings:function(){
    return formatMoney(this.get('savings'));
}.property('savings'),

onSavingsChange:function(){
    newValue=formatMoney(this.savings);
    console.log("formatted value="+newValue);

    //this.savings=newValue;
    //$("#userSavings").val(newValue);
}.observes('savings'),
```

})

the **formatMoney** function is:

```
function formatMoney(inputNumber)
{
try {
        inputNumber = Math.round(inputNumber);
        var n = inputNumber.toString().split(".");
        n[0] = n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return "$" + n.join(".");
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error("Error="+e);
    }
}
```

I want the value in input field to remain in American currency format after user enters a digit. But it's not happening. 
The value of input field is bound to variable **savings** of **IndexController**. when I get the formatted value **newValue**, I want to reflect this in the input field.

I tried both Ember way **this.savings=newValue** and the jQuery Way **$("#userSavings").val(newValue);** but neither works. I can see the output in **formattedSavings** variable but it doesn't reflect on input field.

When I implement it in **jQuery only** (standalone jQuery application), it works. But when Ember comes into picture, it doesn't work.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I am using Ember 1.6.1 and jQuery 1.11. Due to some reasons, I can't upgrade to newer version of Ember.

Comment: You could do `this.set('savings', newValue)`. By why so complicated. Just use a CP, not an observer and do your formatting in the set().

Comment: this.set() doesn't work. The change is not reflected in input field. I have to use observer as there are a lot of computations that are done in observer. I can not post the complete code.

Comment: This should definitely work. Probably something is wrong in your other code then. Its also strange that you call `formatMoney`, just to say this.

Comment: @Lux See the demo by mehanika below. I want the value that the user enters in input field formatted. Eg. user enters 234, I want to show $234 in input field even if user enters only 234. User enters 2334, I want to show $2,334 in input field. I am able to get the formatted value anywhere else on page but not in Input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be to declare the `formatMoney` function inside your `IndexController`and add an `action` to input that triggers the format function

**Controller**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
savings:0,

 formatMoney:function(inputNumber){


   try {

        var n = inputNumber
        .replace(/\D/g,'')
        .toString()
        .split(".");

        n[0] = n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return n.join(".");
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error("Error="+e);
    }
},

  actions:{

    format:function(){

            //Getting the formatted value
      var formattedSavings = this.formatMoney(this.get('savings'));

      //Setting the formated value back to savings
      this.set('savings', formattedSavings);


    }
  }


});
```

Here's a working demo http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zeruyu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I want to show the value that is being shown as "Formatted Savings=" in Input field. I want the formatting to be applied in input field. E.g $34,345 in input field.

Answer (score 1):

The first and important thing here is to understand why its not working and that its a limitation of your ember version:

> Ember will not update the template in the same runloop!

So, the only thing you have to do is to *update the value in the next run loop*!

There are many ways to do this, but probably the easiest is to use `Ember.run.next`:

```
_savings: '',
savings: Ember.computed('_savings', function(key, val) {
    var self = this;
    if(arguments.length === 2) {
        Ember.run.next(function() {
            self.set('_savings', formatMoney(val));
        });
    }
    return Ember.get(this, '_savings');
})
```

You may find other code that will work, but always because you update in the next runloop.